# aiContactSafe change field order in PHP

Tags: php

I created form using aiContactSafe. But the field order is different. How to change the field order? Please tell me the procedure step by step.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the url of the site so we can check to form fields order.........????

Comment: Voting to close this old question as far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Do simple thing crate the form fields in same order as you want and then search the query which is fetching the fields from the db and change the order by  condition id in ASC order.The query might be in the model or in helper....Hopefully this will help you....

Answer (score 0):

The order of the fields is set in the profile. Each profile can have it's own order of fields.
So just access the page with the profile's parameters, scroll down and set the order of the fields you want.